# Object not showing when scene rendered

Tags: javascript, three.js

Please help. Im doing WebGL project with Three.js for my school and am stuck.

What Im trying to achieve is to have an object from blender displayed in center (0,0,0) of scene and than rotate it with keyboard arrows.

here is my init()

```
var scene, camera, renderer;
init();
//animate();
function init() {

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var WIDTH = 880,
      HEIGHT = 550;


  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  document.getElementsByClassName("pw")[0].appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.1, 1000000);
  camera.position.set(5,15,10);

  scene.add(camera);

  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    var WIDTH = 880,
        HEIGHT = 550;
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  });



  //sky dome


    var vertexShader = document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent;
    var fragmentShader = document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent;
    var uniforms = {
    topColor:      { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(0x000053) },
    bottomColor: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0x2626ff ) },
    offset:         { type: "f", value: 100 },
    exponent:     { type: "f", value: 0.7 }
    }

    //skydome

    var skyGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 2000, 32, 15 );
    var skyMat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { vertexShader: vertexShader, fragmentShader: fragmentShader, uniforms: uniforms, side: THREE.BackSide } );

    var sky = new THREE.Mesh( skyGeo, skyMat );
    scene.add( sky );


  //lights


    var light4 = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xfffff3, 0xd7f0ff, 0.2); // soft white light
    scene.add( light4 );


    var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xd7f0ff, 1);
    light2.position.set(1,1,1);
    scene.add(light2);





    var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    var dae

      loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;

      loader.load( 'models/ring.dae', function ( collada ) {
     //dummy1.dae

        dae = collada.scene;

        var skin = collada.skins[ 0 ];

    dae.position.set(0,0,0);//x,z,y- if you think in blender dimensions ;)
    dae.scale.set(7,7,7);

    scene.add(dae);

    });

    //controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    document.addEventListener( 'keydown', onDocumentKeyDown, false );
    //document.addEventListener( 'keyup', onDocumentKeyUp, false );
     renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(render);      
}
```

ever since I comented out controls the object ring.dae is not visible any more... any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed init()

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var WIDTH = 880,
      HEIGHT = 550;


  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  document.getElementsByClassName("pw")[0].appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.1, 1000000);
  camera.position.set(0,2,7);

  scene.add(camera);

  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    var WIDTH = 880,
        HEIGHT = 550;
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  });



  //sky dome


    var vertexShader = document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent;
    var fragmentShader = document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent;
    var uniforms = {
    topColor:      { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(0x000053) },
    bottomColor: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0x2626ff ) },
    offset:         { type: "f", value: 100 },
    exponent:     { type: "f", value: 0.7 }
    }

    //skydome

    var skyGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 2000, 32, 15 );
    var skyMat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { vertexShader: vertexShader, fragmentShader: fragmentShader, uniforms: uniforms, side: THREE.BackSide } );

    var sky = new THREE.Mesh( skyGeo, skyMat );
    scene.add( sky );


  //lights


    var light4 = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xfffff3, 0xd7f0ff, 0.2); // soft white light
    scene.add( light4 );


    var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xd7f0ff, 1);
    light2.position.set(1,1,1);
    scene.add(light2);





    var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();


      loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;

      loader.load( 'models/ring.dae', function ( collada ) {

        ring = collada.scene;

        var skin = collada.skins[ 0 ];

    ring.position.set(0,0,0);//x,z,y- if you think in blender dimensions ;)
    ring.scale.set(7,7,7);

    scene.add(ring);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    });

    //controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    document.addEventListener( 'keydown', onDocumentKeyDown, false );
    //document.addEventListener( 'keyup', onDocumentKeyUp, false );
     render();
```